# Python program will not run correctly

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to get the combination of 10 numbers in sequences of 4's in python.

```
   import itertools

   combs = (itertools.permutations ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 4))
```

When I run it, it says start then skips 2 lines and doesn't do anything. Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: You forgot to call `list()` on it.

Comment: Your program has no output.  How would you be able to see what it's done?

Comment: sorry im still learning python can you leave a comment with the code?

Answer (score 2):

`itertools.permutations` returns an iterator, to fetch items from it you can either use `list()` or loop on it.

**Demo:**

`list()`:

```
>>> list(itertools.permutations ([1,2,3], 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
```

for-loop:

```
>>> for x in itertools.permutations ([1,2,3], 2):
...     print x
...     
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 1)
(2, 3)
(3, 1)
(3, 2)
```

---

And yes `print` is required if you want to see any output from your program. In python shell  `print` is not required as it echoes back the return value, but when executing the program from a **.py** file  `print` is required to see any output.

```
import itertools
combs = list(itertools.permutations ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 4))
print combs
```

Answer (score 2):

permutations return iterator. You should iterator over it to get values.

```
import itertools
combs = itertools.permutations ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 4)
for xs in combs:
    print(xs)
```

Or use `list` to get result as list:

```
import itertools
combs = itertools.permutations ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 4)
list(combs) # => [(1,2,3,4), ...., (10,9,8,7)]
```